# Gif Animated Files in C# have Lower framerates than they should

Tags: c#, performance, gif, frame-rate

ive got a full screen  loading page after my software's done running,which includes a preloader gif file .... which is exactly like the one windows 8 is using for store and metro.

however the problem is that no matter what the fps and speed of the gif file is,the C# windows form will show the same lower fps.

i really dont know what to do with it as i've tried to search the internet to find a solution but whatever i ran into was either unclear or unrelated.

i suspect that somehow the compiler is ignoring the fps integrated within the gif file i imported.
but i do not know how i can set the fps to what it is for the file,or make the IDE/Compiler ignore its rules when it comes to that file..please advise <3

here is the link to the file properties im using
http://preloaders.net/en/search/windows%208
the one in the middle from the top row...it has 75 frames and the rest is as it is...

im currently using a picturebox control to include the gif in my project (its within a winform project)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a normal mishap, GIFs specify the display time for a frame in units of 10 milliseconds.  But timers on Windows, by default, are not sufficiently accurate to time intervals that low.  Timers are updated by the system clock interrupt, it ticks 64 times per second by default.  Giving timers an accuracy no better than 15.625 milliseconds.  In effect, your GIF will playback at 2/3rd speed, give or take.

You can change the outcome by starting another program, like Windows Media Player or a browser like Firefox or Chrome.  And you'll suddenly see your GIF playing back at design speed.

You'll have to do the same thing these programs do, alter the clock interrupt rate to get consistent playback speeds.  You need to pinvoke [timeBeginPeriod](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm/timeBeginPeriod.html), pass 10 to improve the timer accuracy to 10 milliseconds.   You may need to go lower if your UI thread isn't responsive and starts the timer too late.  Be sure to pinvoke timeEndPeriod() again when you no longer need the playback, typically in the FormClosed event handler.

Boilerplate code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        timeBeginPeriod(timerAccuracy);
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e) {
        timeEndPeriod(timerAccuracy);
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
    }

    // Pinvoke:
    private const int timerAccuracy = 10;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern int timeBeginPeriod(int msec);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    public static extern int timeEndPeriod(int msec);
}
```

Comment: Once my mom told me that her little balls game runs better if she leaves the media player open at the background - I just laughed at it back then. Now I'm seeing the explanation :)

Comment: But I'm actually here because now I'm having this problem in my windows forms application, and this code doesn't make any effect neither media player. Is there any other points that I should be aware of while applying this boilerplate code?

Comment: Clearly you are knocking on the wrong door.  Click the Ask Question button, show decent repro code.

Comment: I can, but wouldn't it be a duplicate question then? Here is the question btw; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224074/gifs-framerate-seems-lower-then-actual?noredirect=1#comment56192330_34224074

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen yep there was a time when i discovered if i minimize counter strikes dedicated server (its a game server ) and run windows media player it would reduce the ping time to almost 1/7 of what it  was... I never knew why up untill i got the answer 

Comment: @HansPassant is this behavior changed on winforms  at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, or I'm just not doing it right.

But I found a solution by using a Timer instead. See this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c5ce514f-6fe7-4870-ae3f-c49fb946d294/too-slow-gif?forum=vbgeneral

Yes, it is VB but we can do similar thing in C#. They are close anyway.
The above solution loads the gif into images and loads the images one by one on timer tick.

On my case, I extract all frames in GIF image and load those images into image array on my form constructor, applied similar

```
    public partial class Splash : Form
{
    Image[] images = new Image[60];
    public Splash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadImages();
    }

    private void LoadImages()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 60; i++)
        {
            string path = $@"{Application.StartupPath}\loading\loading{i:0000}.png";
            Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
            images[i - 1] = image;
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i = i % 60;
        pictureBox1.Image = images[i];
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

I was working on loading splash screen and I ended up doing the things I mentioned above. Smooth, and nice. Just adjust the timer interval for higher framerate.

Comment: the accepted answer is no longer valid, also the picturebox uses an ImagenAnimator that have a hardcoded 50ms delay to change the image for the next in the gif, and seems impossible to change that :/ i'm using your anwser, thank you!