# Animated GIF's framerate seems lower than expected

Tags: c#, winforms, time, animated-gif

I have a `winforms` application, which has a gif on it for letting users know about stalling processes.

The problem is it plays much slower than it seems on other applications (chrome, internet explorer).

I have tried the gif on `PictureBox` and `Label` but resulting speed is same. Then after a little research I've come accross [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382400/gif-animated-files-in-c-sharp-have-lower-framerates-than-they-should) question and the answer of legendary @Hans Passant, but unfortunately applying the boilerplate code suggested by him didn't make any difference.

Below is the simple reproducing code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timeBeginPeriod(timerAccuracy);
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosed ( FormClosedEventArgs e )
    {
        timeEndPeriod(timerAccuracy);
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
    }

    // Pinvoke:
    private const int timerAccuracy = 10;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern int timeBeginPeriod ( int msec );
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    public static extern int timeEndPeriod ( int msec );
}
```

And the designer code if needed:

```
partial class Form1
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose ( bool disposing )
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    private void InitializeComponent ()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
        this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        //
        // pictureBox1
        //
        this.pictureBox1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.pictureBox1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox1.Image")));
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 9);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(166, 119);
        this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        //
        // label1
        //
        this.label1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.label1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.label1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("label1.Image")));
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(180, 9);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(158, 119);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 1;
        //
        // Form1
        //
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(346, 134);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
}
```

Both gifs play at same speed, but lower than the actual gif. Is there any other points that I should be aware of while applying this code?

Comment: why are you setting it to 0 accuracy?

Comment: This gif looks like an application resource to me. Can't you simply modify original gif using some gif-editor? Simply make it *slower* e.g. by removing every second frame and prolonging duration of every one which is left. Repeat until results is satisfying.

Comment: I was trying different accuracy values, 0 - 10 - 1000 :) None makes any difference though. Now I've set it back to 10 in the question too.

Comment: @Sinatr, I've added the gif through `properties->image->import`. I don't think it needs to be such a pain to have the real speed effect of a gif anyways.

Comment: Maybe the OS does matter. What is your exact .net framework you compiled this against and on which OS are you running it?

Comment: I'm on my development machine. .net 4.5 is the installed framework. Win8.1 is the OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only get guesses, I doubt anybody will have much luck getting a repro:

- timeBeginPeriod() can technically fail, although that is very unusual when you ask for 10 msec, verify that it returns 0.
- If the image is large then it might just not be able to update fast enough.  Or your UI thread is occupied too much with other duties.  The pixel format of a gif is a poor match with the pixel format of the video adapter on a modern machine.  The conversion is done every time the frame is updated.  It is fairly expensive, especially so if you also force the image to be rescaled (i.e. PictureBox.SizeMode != Normal).  Use Task Manager to verify that your UI thread is not burning 100% core.
- You can get a second opinion about the effective timer period by running `powercfg /energy` from an elevated command prompt.  Do so while your app is running.  It will trundle for a minute and then generate an HTML file that you can look at with your browser.  Reported under the "Platform Timer Resolution:Timer Request Stack" heading, the Requested Period value should be 10000.  Beware that other processes or drivers might also have made requests.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2021-04-02**

The underlying reason behind `PictureBox` animating at a low framerate is because it uses the `ImageAnimator` class behind the scenes which only ever animates at 20 FPS. It has a hard-coded 50ms `Thread.Sleep()` in its worker thread method here:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/ImageAnimator.cs,333

I didn't have access to the Windows Forms source originally when the below was written, but now I'd probably subclass `PictureBox` and make it use a different `ImageAnimator` implementation to reduce that `Thread.Sleep()` to a reasonable value. (`ImageAnimator` is a sealed class so you'd have to copy the code into a new class and reference that in your `PictureBox` instead for smoother animations.)

**Original Answer:**

`PictureBox` is quite a heavyweight control and I'd recommend using something like `Panel` to house your animated GIF instead. In addition, I've read that `PictureBox`'s internal animation timer is low resolution, meaning selecting an update interval of <100ms results in it rounding up to a 100ms update.

Instead you can control the painting and animating yourself. This uses PInvoke because it utilises some kernel timer methods. Example code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

...

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool CreateTimerQueueTimer(out IntPtr phNewTimer,
        IntPtr TimerQueue, WaitOrTimerDelegate Callback, IntPtr Parameter,
        uint DueTime, uint Period, uint Flags);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool ChangeTimerQueueTimer(IntPtr TimerQueue, IntPtr Timer,
        uint DueTime, uint Period);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool DeleteTimerQueueTimer(IntPtr TimerQueue, 
        IntPtr Timer, IntPtr CompletionEvent);
    public delegate void WaitOrTimerDelegate(IntPtr lpParameter, 
        bool TimerOrWaitFired);

    // Holds a reference to the function to be called when the timer
    // fires
    public static WaitOrTimerDelegate UpdateFn;

    public enum ExecuteFlags
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The callback function is queued to an I/O worker thread. This flag should be used if the function should be executed in a thread that waits in an alertable state.
        /// The callback function is queued as an APC. Be sure to address reentrancy issues if the function performs an alertable wait operation.
        /// </summary>
        WT_EXECUTEINIOTHREAD = 0x00000001,
    };

    private Image gif;
    private int frameCount = -1;
    private UInt32[] frameIntervals;
    private int currentFrame = 0;
    private static object locker = new object();
    private IntPtr timerPtr;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Attempt to reduce flicker - all control painting must be
        // done in overridden paint methods
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
            ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        // Set the timer callback
        UpdateFn = new WaitOrTimerDelegate(UpdateFrame);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Replace this with whatever image you're animating
        gif = (Image)Properties.Resources.SomeAnimatedGif;
        // How many frames of animation are there in total?
        frameCount = gif.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Time);
        // Retrieve the frame time property
        PropertyItem propItem = gif.GetPropertyItem(20736);
        int propIndex = 0;
        frameIntervals = new UInt32[frameCount];
        // Each frame can have a different timing - retrieve each of them
        for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
        {
            // NB: intervals are given in hundredths of a second, so need
            // multiplying to match the timer's millisecond interval
            frameIntervals[i] = BitConverter.ToUInt32(propItem.Value, 
                propIndex) * 10;
            // Point to the next interval stored in this property
            propIndex += 4;
        }

        // Show the first frame of the animation
        ShowFrame();
        // Start the animation. We use a TimerQueueTimer which has better
        // resolution than Windows Forms' default one. It should be used
        // instead of the multimedia timer, which has been deprecated
        CreateTimerQueueTimer(out this.timerPtr, IntPtr.Zero, UpdateFn, 
            IntPtr.Zero, frameIntervals[0], 100000,
            (uint)ExecuteFlags.WT_EXECUTEINIOTHREAD);
    }

    private void UpdateFrame(IntPtr lpParam, bool timerOrWaitFired)
    {
        // The timer has elapsed
        // Update the number of the frame to show next
        currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % frameCount;
        // Paint the frame to the panel
        ShowFrame();
        // Re-start the timer after updating its interval to that of
        // the new frame
        ChangeTimerQueueTimer(IntPtr.Zero, this.timerPtr,
            frameIntervals[currentFrame], 100000);
    }

    private void ShowFrame()
    {
        // We need to use a lock as we cannot update the GIF at the
        // same time as it's being drawn
        lock (locker)
        {
            gif.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Time, currentFrame);
        }

        this.panel1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        lock (locker)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(gif, panel1.ClientRectangle);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DeleteTimerQueueTimer(IntPtr.Zero, timerPtr, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

Note: we set the `Period` on the timer calls to `100000` because if you set it to `0` (to indicate a one-off timing), it will only fire once, even if you subsequently call `ChangeTimerQueueTimer`.

The timers are still not suitable for super-accurate timings, but this should still give you a faster update than would otherwise have been possible with `PictureBox`.

Comment: works but it flickers a lot which ruins it.

Comment: @EpicSpeedy My original answer is now more than 5 years old so it's likely that both .NET and the underlying OS has changed since it was written ;) However, I've had a look at the `PictureBox` source code just now and I've updated the answer above with some more information which may be useful for you. Unfortunately the source wasn't available back in 2015.