# Show animated GIF at correct speed

Tags: c#, forms, gif, animated-gif

I want to show an animated GIF image at the correct speed. Most of my GIF's run too slow. I have tried [this code from Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382400/gif-animated-files-in-c-sharp-have-lower-framerates-than-they-should), with no difference in speed. And also [this code from Dave R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224074/animated-gifs-framerate-seems-lower-than-expected?noredirect=1#comment56192330_34224074), but that didn't display any image at all.

This is my code (only shows an animated GIF):

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string gif = @"D:\Visual Studio\Test\lis.gif";
            using (var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(gif, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
            {
                var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                fs.CopyTo(ms);
                ms.Position = 0;
                if (picBox.Image != null) picBox.Image.Dispose();
                picBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Any ideas how I could solve this?

Comment: Still struggling with this. An ideas?