# c# run timer event every 1 milisecond

Tags: c#

Hi I have a question I have a simple timed event that looks like:

```
    public override async Task Execute(uint timedIntervalInMs = 1)
    {
        timer.Interval = timedInterval;
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs evrntArgs)
    {            
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var message = await BuildFrame();
            await sender.Send(message, null);
        });
    }
```

What it does it build simple byte array about 27 bytes and send it via UDP, and I want to send that message each 1 ms, but as i checked with timer sending 1000 request takes about 2 - 3 (so about 330 frames per second)seconds, and that is not what I am aiming for, I suspect that timer is waiting for event to finish its work. Is this true, and can this be avoided so I can start sending frame each ms no matter if event is finished or not?

Comment: What is it that needs an update 1000 times a second?, it seems a bit excessive and even a little DOS-ey.

Comment: Exactly I need it for device stress testing.

Comment: Timer doesn't have such high resolution, the interval is expressed in miliseconds but it doesn't actually have that capability. So basically this won't work. Is it OK to bunch up some messages so that *on average* the target rate is reached?

Comment: Ah okay, makes a little more sense now.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/a/9892273/34092 ?

Comment: At such very rates it stops making sense to use a timer.  Particular important for System.Timers.Timer because it will nest Elapsed event calls if their body takes too long.  Instead delay the code with Thread.Sleep().  You need to make the system clock more accurate to get such a short sleep, pinvoke [timeBeginPeriod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25385470/17034).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be quite useful, the `PeriodicYield<T>` function will return a sequence of results from a generator function.

These results will be delivered at the end of the last full period that didn't complete yet.

Alter `SimpleGenerator` to mimic whatever delay in gneration you would like.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsynchronouslyDelayedEnumerable
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static int Counter;

        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await foreach (var value in PeriodicYield(SimpleGenerator, 1000))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Time\"{DateTimeOffset.UtcNow}\", Value:{value}");
            }
        }

        private static async Task<int> SimpleGenerator()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1500);
            return Interlocked.Increment(ref Counter);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Yield a result periodically.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="generatorAsync">Some generator delegate.</param>
        /// <param name="periodMilliseconds">
        /// The period in milliseconds at which results should be yielded.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="token">A cancellation token.</param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the value to yield.</typeparam>
        /// <returns>A sequence of values.</returns>
        private static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> PeriodicYield<T>(
            Func<Task<T>> generatorAsync,
            int periodMilliseconds,
            CancellationToken token = default)
        {
            // Set up a starting point.
            var last = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

            // Continue until cancelled.
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Get the next value.
                var nextValue = await generatorAsync();

                // Work out the end of the next whole period.
                var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
                var gap = (int)(now - last).TotalMilliseconds;
                var head = gap % periodMilliseconds;
                var tail = periodMilliseconds - head;
                var next = now.AddMilliseconds(tail);

                // Wait for the end of the next whole period with
                // logarithmically shorter delays. 
                while (next >= DateTimeOffset.Now)
                {
                    var delay = (int)(next - DateTimeOffset.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
                    delay = (int)Math.Max(1.0, delay * 0.1);
                    await Task.Delay(delay, token);
                }

                // Check if cancelled.
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // return the value and update the last time.
                yield return nextValue;
                last = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @harol said, Timer doesn't have such high resolution. Because Windows or Linux is not a real-time operating system. It is not possible to trigger an event on precise time. You can trigger an event on approximately time.

Also operating system or your network card driver may decide to wait until the network buffer is full or at a specific value.