# I am having trouble trying to optimise a function to split a GIF into an array of the Image object

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a function which is pretty much a variable-renamed version of the code snippet from https://codingvision.net/c-get-frames-from-a-gif

I am using this to split up the images in a GIF so I am able to iterate over them and play them in a PictureBox to solve the issue highlighted here: [Gif Animated Files in C# have Lower framerates than they should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382400/gif-animated-files-in-c-sharp-have-lower-framerates-than-they-should)

My splitting function:

```
    private Image[] __loading_gif_list;
    private int __frame_count;
    private int __frame_amount;

    private Image[] get_frames(Image _image)
    {
        int frame_count = _image.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Time);
        Image[] frames = new Image[frame_count];

        for (int i = 0; i < frame_count; ++i)
        {
            _image.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Time, i);
            frames[i] = (Image)_image.Clone();
        }

        return frames;
    }
```

My Form Load function:

```
    private void form_main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        __loading_gif_list = get_frames(Properties.Resources.loading);
        __frame_amount = Properties.Resources.loading.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Time);

        loading_picbox.Enabled = false;
    }
```

and my iteration function (a timer can also be used, however I was simply experimenting with this implementation)

```
    private async void loader_updater()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (__frame_count >= __frame_amount) { __frame_count = 1; }
            else { ++__frame_count; }

            loading_picbox.Image = __loading_gif_list[__frame_count - 1];

            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
    }
```

The split function for a 113 frame GIF takes insanely long to complete and the entire program uses an excess of 600mb!! of memory for a 700kb GIF. I am unsure how to optimise the memory usage and speed.

Thank you very much!

Comment: My OCD cant get past the use of underscores :)

Comment: i guess im a freak for liking them haha

Comment: If frames are about 1024×1024 pixels, 4 bytes per pixel, you get 450MB. So it depends how large these frames are.

Comment: I'm confused then. Why is the gif itself only 700kb? Compression?