# C# PictureBox with animated GIF skips Frames

Tags: c#, winforms, gif, picturebox

i have the Problem that my animated gif i used as IMAGE Value in my PictureBox Control is shown slower than showing in Explorer.

I'm using C# Winforms.

Problem here should be that some frames are skipped in execution.

Can someone confirm this issue and maybe have a solution for that?

My Picture Box is for Preloading and works fully in Background Thread.

Is it maybe possible to read the Frames one by one from the gif and animate it selfmade to picturebox?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382400/gif-animated-files-in-c-sharp-have-lower-framerates-than-they-should

Comment: [ImageAnimator.Animate()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/ImageAnimator.cs,177) => [ImageAnimator.AnimateImages50ms()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/ImageAnimator.cs,333). Read the notes on `AnimateImages50ms` and on top of the ImageAnimator class, if you, in any way, are planning on using a PictureBox for animation purposes on a background Thread (ImageAnimator is the class used to the generates the animation in a PictureBox Control). + The Framework version counts.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestions. The solution with the Timer isnt working on my Site. @Jimi How could i implement/change this for my needs?  Is there maybe a better way to show a loading screen?

Comment: You need to post your code, possibly in a way that allows to run it for testing (i.e., [Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). There's no need for background Threads to show an animation. An animation can be rendered at a different speed in different environments: not all application consider custom Frame delays or consider it at all. It's often rendered using a default delay.

Comment: I uploaded a small demo project what is using a picturebox with animated gif from resources. i also put the gif image itself in the zip file. if i run the project -- also with the timer. the animation is slower then the original file opened in windows photo viewer. here is the link: [link](https://kb-it-services.de/projects/repos.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code. ***Since 25 frames per second is displayed, I set the timer to 40, which means one frame every 40 milliseconds.*** `(1000ms / 25 frames = 40ms)`

**step 1. This method shows how to use**

```
static Image[] images;
int frameCount = 0;
private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    //get gif image
    object ezgif_com_video_to_gif = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("ezgif_com_video_to_gif");
    images = getFrames((Image)ezgif_com_video_to_gif);//convert to frames array

    //show frames
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 40;
    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start();
}
```

**step 2. add timer tick**

```
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = images[frameCount];
    frameCount++;
    if (frameCount > images.Length - 1)
        frameCount = 0;
}
```

**step 3. convert gif to frames**

```
Image[] getFrames(Image originalImg)
{
    int numberOfFrames = originalImg.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Time);
    Image[] frames = new Image[numberOfFrames];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++)
    {
        originalImg.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Time, i);
        frames[i] = ((Image)originalImg.Clone());
    }

    return frames;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot! Thats what i was looking for. Works excellent! i had to calculate it for 76 frames and now it's working great.